# A doubt on the Regression of Mankiw, Romer, Weil 1992 paper

Tags: macroeconomics

I'm trying to replicate the regression of the [MRW 1992](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2118477) paper.
([Here's](https://www.nuffield.ox.ac.uk/teaching/economics/bond/mrw.dta) the data, if you're interested)

In the same page where the data set is available, there's this [handout](https://www.nuffield.ox.ac.uk/teaching/economics/bond/OLS%20Regression%20Using%20Stata.pdf) explaining how to replicate the results. In page 2 of this handout, we can see two simple stata commands:

```
li_y=ln(i_y/100) 
 g lpop=ln(0.05+popgrowth/100)
```

My question is why the variables `i_y` (this is Investment over GDP), and `popgrowth`(this is an averaged population growth rate between 1960-1985) are divided by 100?

Nowhere in the MRW 1992 paper, do I read something telling me that it's necessary to divide it by 100, or do I?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Perhaps in the data they are given as percentage points?

Comment: It's just a scaling factor get everything as a decimal.

Comment: Are you aware of the [2013 replication](http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Is_newer_better%3F_Penn_World_Table_Revisions_and_their_impact_on_growth_estimates_(JME_2013))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the data, and it is like @denesp says in his comment: e.g. a $2.60\%=0.0261$ population growth rate is written as $2.60$, a $24\%=0.24$ investment-to-output ratio is written like $24.0$, etc. 
So they must be divided by $100$.

Comment: Thanks Alecos. You're right. I don't know how I missed that ... =D